# grep question - Trying to display lines in a text file that contains more than 2 specific characters

Tags: grep

Got a file like:

```
$ cat file1.txt
123456
1234n5678nn
12n4567890123
123n56n89n1n
```

I am trying:

```
grep -E 'n{3,}' file1.txt
```

to get only lines that have more than two occurrences of `n` in them (do not have to be consecutive) but this did not work.  The output I want is:

```
1234n5678nn
123n56n89n1n
```

Please note I have to do this with `grep` or `egrep` only - cannot use `sed` or `awk`.

Comment: There must be a better way, but the one I can think off the top of my head is `grep -E "n.*n.*n" file1.txt`.

Comment: Now :) on to the fun part - how do I mark this question been answered; thanks!

Comment: @Rfroes87 should copy his comment into the answer section, then you accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
grep -E '(n.*){3,}' file1.txt
```

Or using the method you've already tested and worked fine:

```
grep -E 'n.*n.*n' file1.txt
```